# Unsure why it doesn't print my text file, even though I believe the code is correct

Tags: python

Whenever I run the program, it comes up with an error that I do not expect to happen.

I have a file name as 'LogoArt', and when I enter that into the input it says there is no such file or directory.

```
print('''You will have to enter a file name
Once the file name has been entered, the program will then print out your ASCII art''')
file_name = input('Enter file name: ')
with open(file_name) as file_handle:
    for line in file_handle:
        print(line)
```

I expect the program to print the text document, but it says there is no file or directory.

Comment: add with extension

Comment: Are you sure the file name being entered is exactly the same as the file's full name, extension included? If the file's name is `LogoArt.txt` and the user enters `LogoArt`, Python won't be able to find it.

Comment: Could be a path issue too

Comment: Be sure to use absolute path or relative to where the programming is running from

Comment: How are you running the program? It's too hard to say what's going wrong at the moment. Maybe the program is running with the wrong working directory. Maybe the file has an extension that you can't see in your file explorer.

Comment: The document is in a file in the same folder as my code

Comment: I'm also doing a school project using school computers, that may also be the problem

Comment: I would add a mode to open the file, e.g. 'r' for read. But besides that, I cannot see an issue. Have you tried using the full path as file name?

Comment: That's because there is no such file or directory.

Comment: If you do `import os; print(os.listdir('.'))` at the top of your code, what does it display?

Answer (score 1):

```
    print('''You will have to enter a file name
    Once the file name has been entered, the program will then print out your ASCII art''')
    file_name = input('Enter file name: ')
    new_file = file_name + '.txt'
    with open(new_file_name) as file_handle:
       for line in file_handle:
            print(line)
```